# External environment variable as array

Tags: symfony

How to set external environment variable as array?

If I have environment variable

```
SYMFONY__NSQLOOKUPD__HOSTS=["localhost:4161"]
```

and in config.yml:

```
socloz_nsq:
  lookupd_hosts: %nsqlookupd.hosts%
```

Then I got an error:

```
Invalid type for path "socloz_nsq.lookupd_hosts". Expected array, but got string
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution. Here it is:

in config.yml add to the imports section:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

then create parameters.php file at the same directory where config.yml exists, and look at the following example:

```
<?php

$nsqlookupdhosts = getenv('SYMFONY__NSQLOOKUPD__HOSTS');
$nsqdhosts = getenv('SYMFONY__NSQD__HOSTS');

$container->setParameter('nsqlookupd.hosts.parsed', explode(',', $nsqlookupdhosts));
$container->setParameter('nsqd.hosts.parsed', explode(',', $nsqdhosts));
```

use comma as delimiter in environment variable (you are not restricted to comma, use any)

```
SYMFONY__NSQLOOKUPD__HOSTS=localhost:4161,some.server:2222
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built-in "json" [environment variable processor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html) to decode a JSON string into an array:

```
SYMFONY__NSQLOOKUPD__HOSTS='["localhost:4161"]'

$nsqlookupdhosts: '%env(json:SYMFONY__NSQLOOKUPD__HOSTS)%'
```